# Ubuntu and kubuntu installations failing

Tags: system-installation

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu or kubuntu once the install completes it restarts. Nothing that says remove media or whatever comes up for me. It restarts shows code then black screen then Acer then shows gnu grub menu.

I used a different USB.
I checked for disk errors or that thing in the gnu menu and got 0 errors found.
I removed the USB when the screen went black just before Acer appeared and then it came up with no bootable device found.

I tried 10 times and it’s been like this for 2 weeks.

Please someone help thanks.

In my latest install I got the the grub command line then typed exit and this showed up
(The f12 boot options menu) https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9QDW.jpg

Comment: Should I try using a non Ubuntu distro like opensues?

Comment: Would this tutorial work? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

This maybe is happening because of legacy/uefi settigs in your Bios setup. You are probably installing your Ubuntu in BIOS mode(Legacy).
But it may be disabled in your BIOS setup.

1. So either enable it from bios settings.
2. Or in my opinion Install ubuntu in uefi mode by Making an extra 500 mb partition(Primary) and under file system chose "ESP" EFI System Partition.

*if you have any data on hard disk go with option 1. if no data issues then go with 2 cuz GPT(uefi) and MBR(legacy) partition styles dont work together. *

This 2nd option will install your ubuntu/kubuntu in  uefi mode which is also preferred a lot these days and it will reboot to the system easily after installation completes!!

Comment: I don’t understand number 2 could some please make it more clear to me. I found a more in depth tutorial for anyone having the same issue https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @William Mac option 2 is when you install ubuntu chose 'something else' and add a primary partition and chose ESP EFI partition file system . and g8ve it a size of 500 mb